# How to make 3 columns with the right column having two sections

Tags: css

So essentially I am writing a game in javascript. I have a canvas on the left, a canvas in the middle, a textarea topright, and a canvas bottom right. But I can't seem to get the right CSS code to figure out this layout like the picture.  I want the middle to take up about 50-60% of the middle of the page, and the left and right columns taking the rest of the space. Would be nice if it auto resized with browser window. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Example]

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and add [mcve] of the problem you are facing.

Comment: https://jacobrreed.github.io/StarDefender/

Comment: here is what i tried so far. its like almost there, but they overlap on resize and I had to hard code some percentages in there to get it to look remotely like that

Comment: Don't link yout website, add the ***minimal*** example here in your question as a snippet, there is a button for that in the editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a `container` to hold all the elements and then make smaller containers inside. Target each with `CSS` and set its properties.

Here I set a general `CSS class` `.generalStyles` just to simplify the code.

**You would use something like this:** (run the snippet)

```css
.generalStyles
{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  background-color:#000;
  border-radius:4px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  color:#f00;
  height:100px;
  padding:5px;
  text-align:center;
}

.container
{
  width:100%;
  background-color:#FFF;
}

.leftPanel
{
  width:24%;
  margin:0 1% 0 0;
  
}

.rightPanel
{
  width:24%;
  margin:0 0 0 1%;
  background-color:#FFF;
  padding:0;
}

.middlePanel
{
  width:50%;
  margin:0;
}

.topPanel
{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  height:49.5%;
}

.bottomPanel
{
  width:100%;
  margin:1% 0 0 0;
  height:49.5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container generalStyles">
  <div class="leftPanel generalStyles">left stuff goes here<br/>and more here<br/>and more here<br/>and more here</div>
  <div class="middlePanel generalStyles">middle goes here<br/>and more here<br/>and more here<br/>and more here</div>
  <div class="rightPanel generalStyles">
     <div class="topPanel generalStyles">top stuff<br/>and more here</div>
     <div class="bottomPanel generalStyles">bottom stuff<br/>and more here</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much . perfect

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

h2 {
   text-align:center;
    font-family:arial;
    color:red;
    font-weight:normal;
}

.left {
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius:10px;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:10px;
    height: 300px; 
}

.middle {
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius:10px;
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:10px;
    height: 300px; 
}
.right {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}

.top {
   background-color: #000;
    border-radius:10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 47%;
    padding: 10px;
}

.bottom {
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius:10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 47%;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.row {
   box-sizing:border-box;
    display: flex;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">
    <h2>left</h2>    
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <h2>middle</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
   <div class="top">
     <h2>top right</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
     <h2>bottom right</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that was pretty good. I like Ivans solution a little better though

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="rightDiv"></div>
    <div class="rightDiv"></div>
  </div>
</div
```

and css

```
.container{display:block;width:100%}.left,.middle,.right{width:100px;display:inline-block}.left{border:1px solid red;height:100px}.middle{border:1px solid green;height:100px}.rightDiv{border:1px solid #ff0;height:40px;margin:10px 0}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/z9pe5aq5/1/)